# Двоеточие или запятая? (2)

Tags: запятые, двоеточие, авторская-пунктуация

1. Я всегда говорил: вы идиоты и идиотами будете.
2. Я всегда говорил, вы идиоты и идиотами будете.

Какой вариант правильный и почему?

Comment: Не вижу причин ставить метку "авторская-пунктуация"

Comment: Шутка с блином была неудачная, мягко говоря. Поддерживаю @Niemand.

Comment: А я не только блина имел в виду, но и идиотов тоже.

Comment: Этим словом пользуются многие писатели, в том числе классики, например: Но какой-то идиот вздумал его удерживать и отталкивать. [А. И. Куприн. Гранатовый браслет (1911)] Наверное, в его изначальном значении ИДИОТ, -а; м. [греч. idiōtēs - простолюдин, невежда]

Comment: Даже не смешно. Там, где надо обратить внимание на "интонацию", вы ее как раз и игнорируете. )

Comment: Вы как-то загадками все время говорите: какую интонацию и как я игнорирую?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Правильно: **Я всегдА говорил: вы идиоты и идиотами будете.**

Это классическое БСП с изъяснительным значением, оно заменяет предложение с прямой речью как более простой вариант (обратим внимание, что *говорил*, а не *сказал*). Двоеточие обозначает увеличенную паузу. Здесь важно разделить слова автора и дословное высказывание.

Сравнить: **Говорил же я, вы идиоты и идиотами будете.**

Здесь слова автора оформлены как **вводное предложение** со значением попутного замечания.  Увеличенной паузы нет, поэтому ставится запятая.

Чтобы избежать паузы, применяется **инверсия**  сказуемого.

**Вывод:** Авторская позиция (тире или запятая) реализуется при выборе структуры предложения. Когда предложение уже построено, оно обычно ориентировано на конкретный знак, хотя в некоторых случаях структура предложения допускает варианты. Но здесь явное преимущество за двоеточием.

Comment: >> Двоеточие обозначает увеличенную паузу. Странное объяснение. Нужно оставаться в рамках синтаксиса и не приплетать сюда интонацию, которая может очень сильно различаться. Произносить можно с увеличенной паузой, с обычной паузой и вовсе без паузы. И что тогда прикажете думать? А вот синтаксис остается неизменным.

Comment: Можно ли "не приплетать" интонацию?  Но давайте почитаем учебник: "БСП - это такое сложное предложение, части которого соединяются без помощи союзов и союзных слов. Основное средство связи - ИНТОНАЦИЯ.  Интересно, что они имеют в виду? А о чем говорить Розенталь  в этой теме: Примечание. При отсутствии предупредительной ИНТОНАЦИИ двоеточие "в этих случаях не ставится: Сейчас не поедешь, жарко (Ч.).http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=150#pp150  Значит он не только пользовался интонацией, но еще и определял ее вид.

Comment: Если Вам сложно ориентироваться на паузы, то можно послушать тон речи:  перед двоеточием интонация нисходяще-нисходящая с неполным понижением голоса в конце первой части. Так характеризуется  предупредительно-пояснительная интонация в современных учебниках.

Comment: О чем говорит Розенталь? Давайте сначала посмотрим, ГДЕ говорит это Розенталь. В примечании. То есть. Интонация есть вещь очень и очень вспомогательная, а вы ее всегда выпячиваете на первый план. Да, наверно есть в учебниках разделы, посвященные интонации, –и что? Сначала правила, потом нюансы.

Comment: Жасмин, а Ваш Аладин. Нравится мне Ваш ход мыслей.